# ASPX event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, events, html-lists

I just want to ask what's the problem in my codes here? The OnSelectedIndexChanged event in #cbList is working fine but the ondrop event in #sortable2 is not working. I tried placing it inside and outside the update panel. The code that is being called in the ondrop is in code behind. It just change the dummyText's text.
Here's my code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
        <ContentTemplate>

            <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnSelectedValue" />
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cbList_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="1">
                </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Two" Value="2">
                </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Three" Value="3">
                </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Four" Value="4">
                </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Five" Value="5">
                </asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblSelection" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="dummyText" runat="server" Text="Here"></asp:Label>

            <ul id="sortable2" runat="server" class="connectedSortable" ondrop="Change_Text"></ul>

        </ContentTemplate>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

Comment: Additional info: I have a code that dynamically inserts <li> under #sortable2 using .innerHtml

Answer (score 0):

`ondrop=""` is client side event.
  You cannot wired up this event in code behind.

[Check this link for more information on OnDrop event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536929(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Oh I see, is there any way that I can do something like that in server side? Because I'm doing a draggable <li>s using "jquery-sortable.js" I need the ondrop event to rearrange their numbering, the numbers shows as a badge preceding the list Text.

Comment: I doubt you can that server side. It's better to go with client side.